# Free API I can use to submit short strings

Tags: web-services

I am looking for a website that provides an API that I can use to submit short strings from my program.

For example, if the website was called `https://apiservice.xyz`, they might provide me with a link `https://apiservice.xyz/james123` and whenever someone makes a request to a URL such as `https://apiservice.xyz/james123?value=something123` it will add `something123` to a log I can view.

It should be as simple as possible (nothing overcomplicated like Google Analytics).

Comment: Is it on-topic to ask for websites?